# Php, traffic catcher

Tags: php, html, css, traffic

I'm starting up an image hosting website which also offers pay per view, for example upload an image and it get 1000 views you get $2.00 something along those lines. The only issue I have is that I want to be able to view the traffic per image and what I.P address were used to view the image.

So someone accesses my site they upload an image using a file form input field it then returns a link e.g - domain.com/image.png what could I add to my code so that some sort of tracking is added to each new image thats uploaded.

I will be greatful for any ideas I get!

THANKS

Answer (score 0):

To be brief, you can provide a link to a php script you made like:

```
domain.com/image.php?file=image.png
```

Inside you image.php script you should track the IP using the $_SERVER environment variable, save the hit on your database and finally redirect to the image:

```
header ("Location: " . $_REQUEST['file'] ):
```

That's one strategy.  There are a lot of other ways to solve the problem (maybe better than this one).  Just start to work.

Comment: Thanks, I shall look into this method !

Answer (score 0):

You can configure an *.htaccess* file, so you can catch all requests, manage them.

1. Catch all image requests
2. Determine which image will be displayed
3. Increase datas about that image
4. Display image

Or you can basically create a **show.php** file . And give your users **show.php?id=IMAGEID** . NOw you can track all datas about that image.